# Finiteness of solutions to system of polynomial equations $P(x)P(y)=1$ & $Q(x)Q(y)=1$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Can that finiteness be proved for polynomials $P^n\neq\pm Q^m,\quad n,m>0\;$ by known methods?

---

For univariate polynomials  $A,B,X,Y$ 
$$AX+BY\equiv0$$ iff 
$$A\equiv\frac{HY}{(X,Y)},B\equiv-\frac{HX}{(X,Y)}$$ 
Consider $\deg A<m=\deg Y,\deg B<n=\deg X$. Since $$AX+BY\equiv0 \\ \leftrightarrow \\ (AX+BY)(\alpha_i)=0,\quad i=1,\dots,n+m\ge\deg(AX+BY)+1$$ then representing $A$ in the Lagrange form on $$y_1=\alpha_1,\dots,y_m=\alpha_m$$ 
and $B$ in the Lagrange form on $$x_1=\alpha_{m+1},\dots,x_n=\alpha_{m+n}$$
 one obtains homogeneous linear system with matrix of coefficients 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
Y(x_1)\prod_{i=2}^n(x_1-x_i) & 0 & \dots & X(x_1)\prod_{i=2}^m(x_1-y_i) & X(x_1)(x_1-y_1)\prod_{i=3}^m(x_1-y_i) & \dots \\
\vdots \\
Y(y_1)\prod_{i=1}^n(y_1-x_i) & Y(y_1)(y_1-x_1)\prod_{i=1}^m(y_1-x_i) & \dots & X(y_1)\prod_{i=2}^m(y_1-y_i) & 0 & \dots \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Determinant of this matrix equals to zero iff $(X,Y)=1$.

Finiteness of solutions of initial system is equivalent to $$(PP(y)-1,QQ(y)-1)=1$$ Let 
$$P(x)=p(x-p_1)\dots(x-p_\nu)(x-r_1)\dots(x-r_\lambda) \\
Q(x)=q(x-q_1)\dots(x-q_\mu)(x-r_1)\dots(x-r_\lambda)\neq const,$$
where 
$$p_i\neq q_j,p_i\neq r_j,q_i\neq r_j, \\
p_1\neq p_k,q_i\neq q_k,r_i\neq r_k$$ for $$i\neq k$$ and $$\nu>\mu$$
Substitution 
$$X=PP(y)-1,Y=QQ(y)-1 \\
x_1=p_1,\dots,x_\nu=p_\nu,x_{\nu+1}=r_1,\dots \\
y_1=q_1,\dots,y_\mu=q_\mu,y_{\mu+1}=a_1,\dots$$
($a_i\neq p_j,a_i\neq q_j,a_i\neq r_j,a_i\neq a_k$ for $i\neq k$) yelds polinomial expression of determinant on y that have $$\deg=\nu(\mu+\lambda)+(\mu+\lambda)(\nu+\lambda)=(n-\lambda)m+mn=2mn-m\lambda$$

-

Thus initial system has finite number of solutions for inconstant polinomials with different degrees and without multiple roots.

Comment: My first reaction is that you also need to exclude cases  like $Q=P^2$ (or $P^2=Q^3$ and other such power combos). [Bezout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem) from algebraic geometry is the tool I would try to use.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, I have corrected.

Comment: please make your post more readable. use \$\$ instead of \$.